# How do I detect if CollectionView is scrolled programmatically or by user?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a CollectionView and I need to determine if it has been scrolled programmatically or if the user has scrolled the CollectionView.

Both of these events are triggering the `Scrolled` event.

Comment: shouldn't you know if you are programatically calling `ScrollTo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if the `CollectionView` is being scrolled programmatically, you should know, because you're the one doing it.

From your question, I infer that you're trying to make a distinction somewhere where you don't have a direct connection to the `CollectionView` in question, possibly because you're trying to keep concerns separated.

One thing that you could do is subclass the `CollectionView` and wrap the calls to the `CollectionView.ScrollTo()` method(s) and invoke a separate event handler:

```cs
public ProgScrollEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Index { get; init; }

    public ProgScrollEventArgs(int index)
    {
        Index = index;
    }
}

public MyCollectionView : CollectionView
{
    public event EventHandler<ProgScrollEventArgs> ProgrammaticallyScrolled;

    // New method to call
    public void ScrollToIndex(int index)
    {
        // Relay call to base method
        ScrollTo(index);

        // Invoke separate event handler
        ProgrammaticallyScrolled?.Invoke(this, new ProgScrollEventArgs(index));
    }
}
```

Then, you use the `MyCollectionView` class instead of `CollectionView` everywhere in your XAML and subscribe to the `ProgrammaticallyScrolled` event:

```xml
<MyCollectionView
    x:Name="MyCollectionView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}"
    ProgrammaticallyScrolled="OnProgScroll" />
```

In the code-behind you'll add the event handler:

```cs
private void OnProgScroll(object sender, ProgScrollEventArgs e)
{
    // handle event here
}
```

You will need to use the new `ScrollToIndex()` method for programmatic scrolling:

```cs
MyCollectionView.ScrollToIndex(5);
```

Alternatively, you can also subscribe to the event in the code-behind:

```cs
MyCollectionView.ProgrammaticallyScrolled += OnProgScroll;
```